# Tolerant XML pretty printer

Tags: linux, web-apps, xml

I develop an application that sometimes has to generate XML code, without using an XML library, with the effect that a bug could have the effect that the XML is not well formed.

I am quite sure that other people, in various circumstances, have had to go through not well formed XML, which can be a very difficult task since the usual tools don't work.

So I was wondering whether there exists a software that is able to attempt pretty printing XML code even if it is not well formed.

Something that runs on Linux or as a web service would be preferred.